# How to force a Save As dialog when streaming a PDF attachment

Tags: php, header, pdf-generation

I am using the following code to stream a pdf to the browser:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=file.pdf");
echo $pdf;
```

Works fine, except (in Chrome anyhow) it just saves the file "file.pdf" - it does not prompt a Save As dialog so I can rename the file, if I choose.

I suspect this may be one of those browser-dependent things, but is it possible to force a Save As dialog with the php headers when streaming a pdf for download?

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Comment: If you try downloading other files using Chrome, you'll find that it uses that behavior pretty much globally. (Or, if not, that's at least what I've experienced. Maybe it's a setting of some kind)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They most likely have *Ask where to save each file before downloading* unchecked (Advanced Settings). If this is the case, there's nothing you can do as this is their preference.

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is controlled by the browser settings, so I don't think theres a way to force the "Save as" dialog to be opened.

You could try not specifying a name for the file, but I do think that it will just inherit the scripts name instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
Content-Type = application/download
```