# Extjs file path chooser

Tags: file, extjs, extjs4

I have rest client with extjs and i want to let the user choose where to save the file. The file is saved as a pdf on the client machine via java and itextpdf library. I have to send only file path to the client back-end . How to create 'save as' dialog to get only file path?
There is xtype: filefield in extjs but it is used to choose existing file. I need to choose path to the new file.

Comment: Are you trying to choose the path to save the file on your client machine? If so this is the browsers job and can't be controlled via javascript. If you are trying to select a location on the server to save the file. You would have to build a tree component that queries the server for its file structure and select the path that way. The wording of your question makes it a bit difficult to understand what you are trying to attempt.

Comment: @JamieSutherland I have to choose the path to save the file on client machine. Server sends needed data to client. Client has java back-end  which saves file on disk

Comment: Saving a file client side is a browsers job. You can not do anything to dictate how a browser handles this I'm afraid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474553/how-to-force-a-save-as-dialog-when-streaming-a-pdf-attachment

Comment: Well, it is one option. User can manually write path... But it isn't user friendly...